# Notification Body problems

Tags: xcode

I have this line of code for a notification:

[notification setAlertBody:(@"%@",placesData[counter])];

placeData is an array and [counter] is a counter that switches the text data in the notification but it is not working for me. can you help me please? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
[notification setAlertBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",placesData[counter]]];
```

If that does not work, the array is probably nil, empty or does not contain an NSString.

You can only use the code you use if you use a string constant: e.g.

```
[notification setAlertBody:@"Error!"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1 `notification` is either nil or not a UILocalNotification.

2 `placedData[counter]` is either nil, empty or something other than an NSString.

Without more information or code it's impossible to say more.